# Unable to Include Ackermann Messages in ROS2 C++ Node

Tags: ros2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am using ROS2 Dashing on Ubuntu 18.04 and am receiving the error
`fatal error: ackermann_msgs/msg/AckermannDrive.hpp: No such file or directory #include "ackermann_msgs/msg/AckermannDrive.hpp"` when trying to `colcon build --symlink-install` a custom package with a rclcpp node. The headers files in the node are as follows

`#include "rclcpp/rclcpp.hpp"`

`#include "sensor_msgs/msg/joy.hpp"`

`#include "ackermann_msgs/msg/AckermannDriveStamped.hpp"`

All std_msgs, sensor_msgs, and geometry_msgs include fine and I have the lines `find_package(ackermann_msgs REQUIRED)`  and `ament_target_dependencies(usb_hw_interface rclcpp ackermann_msgs sensor_msgs)` in my CMakeLists.txt and the line   `<depend>ackermann_msgs</depend>` in my package.xml. I have scoured the internet for similar problems and have looked over my code a multitude of times without luck. I can confirm that ackermann_msgs are installed in my `/opt/ros/dashing/share` and that they appear when I run `ros2 msg list`. Any help is greatly appreciated.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/338820/unable-to-include-ackermann-messages-in-ros2-c++-node/) by [mequi](https://answers.ros.org/users/49860/mequi/) on ROS Answers with karma: 111 on 2019-11-28

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Looking at the include the joy message, it looks like a lowercase_underscore pattern is used.
Can you have a look at the content of `/opt/ros/dashing/include/ackermann_msgs/msg` ?

Looks like including `ackermann_msgs/msg/ackermann_drive_stamped.hpp` would be more appropriate for a c++ node.

---

Originally posted by [marguedas](https://answers.ros.org/users/19307/marguedas/) with karma: 3606 on 2019-11-28

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0